# Is there any mechanism provided by Matter protocol to add a new kind of Device Type? If so, What is the process and Is there any limitations doing so?

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

As part of POC I am trying to understand if the Matter protocol allows adding a new Device Type or not as what BLE has like custom services for specific to manufacturers.

I have found some details from the specification provided by CSA for Matter in it's core spec document. There is one section about creation of new Cluster but as per document it says we need to reuse or extend existing Cluster provided by Matter. But it is still unclear on a broader level.

I want to know if there's any possibility to add a new kind of Device Type into Matter protocol or not? If there's any provision, what are the limitations on that?

Comment: I could be wrong but you would probably need to become a member on the "contributor" level (and pay the member fee), if you aren't already, for contributing new clusters to the standard.

Comment: The specification document says: "7.16. Non-Standard: This architecture model provides mechanisms for non-standard or manufacturer specific items such as clusters, commands, events, attributes and attribute data fields. These items MAY be supported on a certified product.  ..."

Answer (score 1):

You can create customizable clusters to work as per your needs or requirements but as of now there is no support for adding a new kind of Device Type into Matter protocol.